# whereJsonContains giving me "Maximum function nesting level of '512' reached, aborting!"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have discount table where I have rules column which is a json and looks like this

```
rules:{"books":{"id":1,"name":"Product"....others}..others}
```

and When I am running this function

```
public function something(){
    return Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books->id',1)->first();
}
```

But this is giving me that error

Comment: You have somewhere a recursive call. How deep is your JSON ?

Comment: Try:
return Discount::whereJsonContains('rules->books->id',['id' => 1])->first();

Comment: please share your Discount model full code